# pie() does not accept an array of objects

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js

I have the following code:

```
public data = [
  {
    value: 61,
    color: 'orange',
  },
  {
    value: 29,
    color: 'white',
  },
  {
    value: 10,
    color: 'blue',
  },
];
```

```
  public pie = d3
    .pie()
    .padAngle(0)
    .value((d: any) => d.value);
```

```
const arcs = this.pie(this.data);
```

Which is basically the outcome of some of the various tutorials about building a donut chart with d3js.

Now I would like to add a custom interface for the items in the data array and also properly type the `d` parameter in the `.value()` function.

The problem is, that the `@types/d3` package defines the expected data array as `number[]` and the `d` parameter as `number`.

Which means that I cannot use a custom interface for the data items. The typings package for D3 seems to be wrong in this case because all the tutorials I've read do it this way and the code works just fine.

What are my options in this case? Are there any workarounds? Can I override the typings that get into my way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`d3`'s `pie` accepts a generic just for that.

Here's how to solve this:

```
interface IData {
  value: number;
  color: string;
}

const data: IData[] = [
  {
    value: 61,
    color: 'orange',
  },
  {
    value: 29,
    color: 'white',
  },
  {
    value: 10,
    color: 'blue',
  },
];

const pie = d3
  .pie<IData>()
  .padAngle(0)
  .value(d => d.value);

const arcs = pie(data);
```